# \x00 treated as null byte and doesnt count

Tags: linux, shell, hex, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to learn about stack overflow, when I want to overwrite the eip register i type in my shell this command:

```
run $(perl -e 'print "\xb8\x06\x40\x00" x 20;')
```

it supposed to overwrite the dwords 20 times but the problem is that the last hex number x00 isn't count because its a null byte and I don't know what to replace it with , i have tried many combinations but i cant seem to find the right one.

this is the out put

```
0x7fffffffe230: 0xf7ff74c0  0x00007fff  0xffffe643  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe240: **0xb84006b8    0x06b84006  0x4006b840  0xb84006b8
0x7fffffffe250: 0x06b84006  0x4006b840  0xb84006b8  0x06b84006
0x7fffffffe260: 0x4006b840  0xb84006b8  0x06b84006  0x4006b840
0x7fffffffe270: 0xb84006b8  0x06b84006  0x4006b840**    0x00000000
0x7fffffffe280: 0x004006f0  0x00000000  0xf7a57870  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe290: 0xffffe368  0x00007fff  0xffffe368  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe2a0: 0x00000000  0x00000002  0x00400669  0x00000000
```

look at the addresses like 0xb84006b8 it missing the x00..

thanks for help:)

Comment: Perl is printing the null byte just fine.  You can verify this by piping the output into a hex dump utility: `perl -e 'print "\xb8\x06\x40\x00" x 20;' | xxd`  The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: what do you get when  you type `which run`? I'm not used to seeing such a command in Linux. Good luck.

Comment: Mr.Llama the command you gave doesn't work but im still pretty sure this is the problem cuz what else could it be ? any other number is working and if you remove the \ it will work 1 time but not 20 so it's weird to me
and for shellter which run doesnt work it says undefined command

Comment: `undefined command` in regards to `which`, or to `run`?  What do you get if  you type `uname -srv`? Good luck.

Comment: "Linux 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-7kali2 (2016-01-27)"
btw my run command is in the gdb debugger that's why i use run

Comment: did you try `run perl ....;` (without the `$(...)`)? Good luck.

Comment: yes i did and it doesnt do anything